# How to make a tablelayout scroll vertically and horizontally

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout, horizontalscrollview, vertical-scrolling

How can I make a tablelayout scroll horizontally and vertically? The columns of this tablelayout are generated dynamically. At this moment he is only sliding vertically.

In some situations the information contained in the tablelayout line will be too large and you will need to slide horizontally to view it completely.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizon`enter code here`tal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/activity_spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/activity_edt1"
                android:labelFor="@+id/consultaCliente_edt1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                style="@style/EditText" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_bt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/bt1"
                android:src="@drawable/search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/activity_spinner2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/activity_spinner3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_bt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:contentDescription="@string/bt2"
                android:src="@drawable/information" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/activity_scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >
            </TableLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="0sp"
                android:paddingEnd="10sp"
                android:text="@string/txt1"
                style="@style/TextViewBlack" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activity_scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/activity_horizontalView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </TableLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Which libraries are needed for ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

**I also encountered the same issue, and the responses I found here were not helpful. I had to create my own functional solution.**

**This is my solution:**

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabla"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```